# Gzip Mutliple files using single command

Tags: linux, compression, csv

Want to Gzip my all the .csv files into a gzip file.

I am using this command.

```
gzip *.csv;
```

***Problem*** File contains '//' in its name that's why command is giving error.

**Error** : - '//File.csv' is not a directory or file.

So please suggest me what ways i can do this successfully.

one solution i thought.

```
gzip '//File1.csv' '//File2.csv' '//File3.csv'
```

Please suggest me if this is the right way to perform the same.